# How to fake a json post request in Play 2.1.1

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

T tried a lot of approaches in play java for faking a post request to my controller, but nothing worked for me.

```
callAction(controllers.routes.ref.MyController.myFunction(), fakeRequest().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withJsonBody(json));
```

It always says `the method fakeRequest() is undefinded` in eclipse.

Comment: You didn't provide much code, so my first guess is that it's undefined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24850328/243233

Answer (score 1):

Add import static play.test.Helpers.*