# Play: How to Create a Fake Request in Production Code

Tags: scala, playframework

`FakeRequest` comes from artifact `play-test` and is added to the project only in the test scope... but I need to create a kind of fake request just to invoke a method that takes an implicit `RequestHeader`:

```
import play.api.test._

...

implicit val request = FakeRequest(
    Helpers.POST,
    controllers.routes.auth.Users.triggerPasswordReset(superuser.email.get).url,
    FakeHeaders(),
    ""
)

// createToken takes an implict RequestHeader
createToken(TokenType.Reset, account).map { token =>
    EmailHelper.sendPasswordResetEmail(user.email.get, token.asJwt)
    ...
}
```

How do I import `FakeRequest` in the compile scope? Is there a better option? Or shall I invoke the controller's method directly?

Comment: Can’t you factor out the code into a function and call that from both places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your Build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-test" % "2.2.1" % "compile"
)
```

Make sure to change "2.2.1" to be whatever version of Play your are using.

This should expose the play test classes to the compile scope.

Cheers!